# Upgrading RAM on Toshiba Satellite Radius 11 L15W-B1303

Tags: laptop, memory, installation, toshiba-laptop, ddr3

I'm trying to figure out why Toshiba says that I can't upgrade the RAM on a Toshiba Satellite Radius 11 L15W-B1303 that I just bought.  It has 2GB DDR3L 1600MHz and says: (Memory is not user replaceable).

http://www.toshiba.com/us/computers/laptops/satellite/Radius11/L15W-B1303

Why not??  I would like to upgrade the ssd as well. Will I not be able to do that, either?

My idea was to buy a cheap laptop and then upgrade it myself to save some money.  It hasn't arrived yet so I haven't hade the opportunity to take it apart and check out the inside.  Should be here in a couple of days.  I've been searching the web for the last couple of hours and not getting anywhere.  Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

-Stephen

Comment: It is possible that they have soldered the memory directly to the motherboard in order to save costs. The "emmc" suggests that it could not be a standard sata ssd either. This is what you can expect if you are buying the cheapest hardware, lots of compromises to make it as cheap as possible and usually all at the expense of upgradability.

Comment: I own a soldering iron and am fairly good at it thanks to my uncle who used to own a tv/vcr repair shop.  Would it be possible to remove the memory if it is soldered to the motherboard and replace it with more?

Comment: A soldering iron is unlikely to be enough. If you had a BGA rework station then maybe, but it would be more effort than it is worth.

Comment: Ok, so I figured out what the eMMC means.  It's flash memory.  There's a great explanation of the difference between it and a true solid state drive at [eMMC vs. SSD: Not All Solid-State Storage is Equal](http://www.howtogeek.com/196541/emmc-vs.-ssd-not-all-solid-state-storage-is-equal/).

Answer (score -1):

these are so new that you probably still have a warranty.  you can check this on Toshiba's web site by inputting the serial and model number off of the tag.  I bought mine used on ebay and if the original owner did not register it, then you can register it and get the full one year warranty and 60 days of free Toshiba tech support.

Comment: How would the warranty help in this situation? There is nothing wrong with the laptop in the question. In fact, doing some of the upgrades to it might void the warranty.